# counts number of each word with a function

Tags: javascript

```
<body>

 <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
 <button id="button">Click</button>


 <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

how can I make a function that counts the number of each word?

Then go through each element from part 1, for each word I will find the position of this word in "word[]"

part 1:

```
 var txt = document.getElementById("text");
 var btn = document.getElementById("button");

 var array;

 btn.addEventListener("click", getText);

 function getText(){
    array = txt.value.split(/[\n <>.,\?]/);
    console.log(array);
}
```

Part 2:

```
 function countWord(){
  var words = [];
  var count = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 var txt = document.getElementById("text");
 var btn = document.getElementById("button");

 btn.addEventListener("click", getText);

 function getText(){
    var words = txt.value.split(/[\n <>.,\?]/);
    console.log(words);

    var wordCount = words.length;
    console.log(wordCount);
}
```

`words` is already a `word[]`, and in order to get the amount of `words` in the `Array`, then just ask for `words.length`, and it will give you have many `values` are in the `Array`